# How do I solve memory leaks that are reported to reside in STL string?

Tags: c++, string, stl, valgrind, poco-libraries

For a school project, we have to send big files across the network., we must use Poco::XML for our data.

After our files are send over the network, it appears that the memory does not free.

Here is an example for a file of `~9 Mb` on the receiving part:

`valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes -v ourExecutable parms` returns:

```
 12,880,736 bytes in 37 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 101 of 101
    at 0x4C2747E: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
    by 0x5A3AC88: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
    by 0x5A3BC4A: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
    by 0x5A3C1BB: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
    by 0x5A3C68E: std::string::append(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
    by 0x5202359: Poco::XML::Element::innerText() const (in /home/tomwij/IGS/trunk/Project/external/lib/libPocoXML.so.8)
    by 0x4145BF: NodeProtocol::getChildNodeStrValue(Poco::XML::Element*, std::string) (NodeProtocol.cpp:82)
    by 0x41544F: NodeProtocol::deserialize(std::string const&) (NodeProtocol.cpp:200)
    by 0x40B088: Node::handleClientPacket(PriorityElement*) (Node.cpp:760)
    by 0x40A04C: Node::handlePackets() (Node.cpp:574)
    by 0x4078EA: Node::run() (Node.cpp:162)
    by 0x40772D: Node::activate() (Node.cpp:138)

 LEAK SUMMARY:
    definitely lost: 12,888,036 bytes in 190 blocks
    indirectly lost: 644,979 bytes in 1,355 blocks
      possibly lost: 10,089 bytes in 27 blocks
    still reachable: 306,020 bytes in 43 blocks
         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

The function which is right before Poco is

```
const string NodeProtocol::getChildNodeStrValue(Element * elem, string child)
{
    Element*  tempNode = elem->getChildElement(child);
    XMLString result(tempNode->innerText());
    string ret = string(fromXMLString(result));
    result.clear();
    return ret;
}
```

which calls

```
XMLString Element::innerText() const
{
    XMLString result;
    Node* pChild = firstChild();
    while (pChild)
    {
        result.append(pChild->innerText());
        pChild = pChild->nextSibling();
    }
    return result;
}
```

(Note that `XMLString` is `std::string`)

**Why is the `append` of STL string leaking memory?**

If I just assign instead of using the copy constructors it gives the same problem.

---

**EDIT:**

I'm using the latest stable GNU GCC 4.4.4 on Gentoo x64 (linux-2.6.34-gentoo-r12).

More functions from the call stack (stripped irrelevant big chunks of code / if structures):

```
Command * NodeProtocol::deserialize(const string & msg)
{
    DOMParser xmlParser;

    // Get the root node.
    AutoPtr<Document> doc = xmlParser.parseString(msg);
    AutoPtr<Element> rootElement = doc->documentElement();

    string root = fromXMLString(rootElement->nodeName());
    string name = getChildNodeStrValue(rootElement, "name");
    string data = getChildNodeStrValue(rootElement, "data");
    return new PutCommand(name, data);
}
```

and

```
void Node::handleClientPacket(PriorityElement * prio)
{
        Command * command = NodeProtocol::deserialize(prio->fPacket);

        // CUT: Access some properties of command, let the command execute.

        delete command;
}
```

and

```
void Node::handlePackets()
{
    PriorityElement * prio = fQueue->top();
    fQueue->pop();

    if (prio->fSource == kCLIENT)
        handleClientPacket(prio);
    else if (prio->fSource == kNODE)
        handleNodePacket(prio);

    delete prio;
}
```

where `fQueue` is:

```
priority_queue< PriorityElement*,  vector<PriorityElement*>, ComparisonFunction >
```

Comment: You didn't show the code of the `OurExecutable::handleClientPacket` function, or any above it in the call stack. None of the functions whose code you posted show any dynamic allocation. So the leak can't be there.

Comment: Do you do any dynamic memory allocation yourself?

Comment: What compiler is used (and its version)? What standard library implementation is used?

Comment: @MartinhoFernandes: Are you 100% that it's not in Poco? I've added more information.

Comment: @Marlon: Yes, except for the AutoPtr in `deserialize` I do; I've added more information.

Comment: @SergeDundick: Added that information in the question right after `EDIT:`, how do I see the STL version? This also happens on `gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)`, my co-developer's PC.

Comment: Removed any namespace stuff, `OurExecutable` renamed to `Node` for clarification.

Comment: @TomWij: one piece of advice --> try to use smart pointers (`boost::scoped_ptr` would do nicely here, if you don't want boost, just grab the file or recreate it). If there is any exception in your code, it'll leak too.

Comment: @Matthieu: Yeah, on the chat we talked about preferring `value > reference > pointer` and using `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` when necessary. Unless the library wants you to use something different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would make this a comment, but apparently I don't have the rep. Have you remembered to make the destructor for `Command` virtual? If `name` or `data` are fields of `PutCommand` rather than `Command` and the `Command` destructor is not virtual, they may not be freed properly when you delete `command` in `handleClientPacket`.

Comment: Glad you didn't made this a comment. Apparently the actual problem seemed to be far away from the source... :/

Comment: **Lesson learned:** Don't necessarily look at the source, also see where it gets stored and what happens with it.